# How to ensure that follow specific google map road while using Google Map API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am trying to draw a path on roads and follow some given points.I am using Google Directions API to follow the roads.I put some markers on roads and link these points with polylines.I need to follow the red line but it follows and draws blue lines.How can I ensure this?

[image]

Comment: it may be an error with google maps itself route the place on google maps itself and if it does the same thing report it as an error

Answer (score 2):

Verify if it is a road at all by zooming in.
Also Make sure that u can tread in that direction in the road.Sometimes roads are one way, So google automatically chalks out an alternative path.
Hope this helps.

Comment: First thank you very much for your attention.But I don't understand what did you mean exactly.For example when I give some coordinates in an order path is drawn correctly.While  when I give these coordinates in a reverse order I face the problem above.Did you talk about this issue?If it is,how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Reversing the coordinates is like swapping source and destination. Just like I said in the answer, roads needn't always function both the ways, meaning u can go from X point to Y point on a road, but perhaps u can't do the same from Y to X. So, google finds out some other plausible path and not the path u wish to go.  If it helps, U may change the mode of viewing the path, as in u may chose walking option or auto mobile option, or Bus option etc. Paths that google shows are selective to these options. All paths cant be traversed by all options..

Comment: I need to show some stations on the road at both direction.I swapped the source and the destination,but of course stations aren't at the same coordinates,only  start and end points of its path is same.So problem can't be solved.